# Using regex to get the value between two characters (Python 3)

Tags: python, regex

```
import re

value = "world_wide='test1/one/two', " \
        "stage_test='ALPHA', world_wide='test2/one/two', " \
        "stage_test='GAMMA', world_wide='test3/one/two', " \
        "stage_test='GAMMA', world_wide='test4/one/two', " \
        "stage_test='ALPHA', world_wide='test5/one/two', " \
        "stage_test='GAMMA', world_wide='test6/one/two', " \
        "stage_test='GAMMA"

pattern = r"(world_wide=\'.*\')"

for match in re.findall(pattern, str(value)):
    print ("\n", match)
```

Trying to filter for a specific output given a string value. With the code above the following output is given:

```
 world_wide='test1/one/two', stage_test='ALPHA', world_wide='test2/one/two', stage_test='GAMMA', world_wide='test3/one/two', stage_test='GAMMA', world_wide='test4/one/two', stage_test='ALPHA', world_wide='test5/one/two', stage_test='GAMMA', world_wide='test6/one/two', stage_test='
```

What I'm trying to get is: if the string matches a specific condition such as:

if 'world_wide=' is found, return the following value between the two characters. In this case, this would be two single quotes excluding the '/one/two'.

Desired output:

```
>>>test1
test2
test3
test4
.........
```

Comment: hello welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you reformat your question so that in the input string `value` is more readable? It seems like you have a quote closing problem in your post.

Comment: corrected the formatting a bit to make it more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following expression:

```
world_wide='([^/]+)
# world_wide='
# capture anything not a / into group 1
```

---

In `Python` this is:

```
import re

value = "world_wide='test1/one/two', " \
        "stage_test='ALPHA', world_wide='test2/one/two', " \
        "stage_test='GAMMA', world_wide='test3/one/two', " \
        "stage_test='GAMMA', world_wide='test4/one/two', " \
        "stage_test='ALPHA', world_wide='test5/one/two', " \
        "stage_test='GAMMA', world_wide='test6/one/two', " \
        "stage_test='GAMMA"

rx = re.compile(r'''world_wide='([^/]+)''')
parts = rx.findall(value)
print(parts)
```

This yields a list containing

```
['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5', 'test6']
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/OkEejf/1).

Answer (score 0):

The regex you're looking for is probably as simple as `pattern = r"world_wide='(.*)\/one"`. Here's a demo: https://regexr.com/3qffn

```
>>> import re
>>> value = ("world_wide='test1/one/two',stage_test='ALPHA')>,")
>>> pattern = r"world_wide='(.*)\/one"
>>> re.finall(pattern, value)
['test1']
```

What's making your question particularly hard to answer is that I think you have some typos in your example. On line 6 where you have `stage_test='GAMMA')>]",`
 I think you actually mean just `stage_test='GAMMA')>,`. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Once I've to deal with regex, I always use https://regex101.com which is pretty nice and easy for fast prototyping and multiple case testing. For your regex please see the following link https://regex101.com/r/TLXDXl/1. My suggested pattern is:

r'world_wide='(?Ptest\d+)/'

which filters tries to match prefix using 'world_wide=', then matches the group named 'name', which starts with 'test' followed by one or more digit. more general approach would be to use '[\w\d]+' for name which will match any letter and digit.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. Found regex101.com super useful.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use just `split()` instead of `re`?:

```
for item in value.split(','):
    if 'world_wide' in item:
        world_parts = item.split('\'')
        test_parts = world_parts[1].split('/')

        if 'test' in test_parts[0]:
            print(test_parts[0])
```

Comment: Considering using this option.  Thanks!